# Multisite - Echo admins profile meta

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, templates, user-meta, profiles

I'm having a problem with echoing the admin's profile meta in a custom post type template. It used to work, but for some reason it's not working anymore. I'm not aware of any changes made that would cause such behavior.

This is the code I'm using in the loop:

```
<p>
<?php
$thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;
$user_id_from_email = get_user_id_from_string( get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email'));
$phone_number = get_user_meta($user_id_from_email, 'phone', true);
if($phone_number!='') { ?>
<?php echo $phone_number; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?></p>
```

I've also tried this:

```
<?php
global $current_blog;
$thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;
$user_id_from_email = get_user_id_from_string( get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email'));
$details = get_userdata($user_id_from_email);
if ($details->nickname) echo $details->nickname;
?>
```

And this:

```
<?php
global $current_blog;
$thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;
$user_id_from_email = get_user_id_from_string( get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email'));
$firm_name = get_user_meta($user_id_from_email, 'nickname', true);
if($firm_name!='') { ?>
<?php echo $firm_name; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

That echoes nothing. The following code echoes *some* data, but it seems to be doing so for the super admin:

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      echo $user_info->last_name .  ", " . $user_info->first_name . "\n";
?>
```

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Comment: I dont see where `$current_blog` is defined. You need to add `global $current_blog` before using it. For more information you can check the [`codex`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Global_Variables)

Comment: I forgot to mention i did that as well, ill update my question. @MarutiMohanty

Comment: As an aside, you can use [`get_current_blog_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) instead of globalizing `$current_blog`.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. I wont be able to provide the blog id cause it has to work for all sites made on the network. @PatJ

Comment: I mean, there's a WordPress function -- [`get_current_blog_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_blog_id) -- that will return the current blog ID, thus removing the need for your `global $current_blog; $thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;` code. You can use `$thisblog = get_current_blog_id();` instead.

Comment: @PatJ like this? `<?php
$thisblog = get_current_blog_id();
$user_id_from_email = get_user_id_from_string( get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email'));
$details = get_userdata($user_id_from_email);
if ($details->nickname) echo $details->nickname;
?>` cause i still get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Codex, [`get_user_id_from_string()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_id_from_string) is deprecated, and should be replaced with [`get_user_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by).

```
<p>
<?php
$thisblog = get_current_blog_id();  // probably don't need this anymore
$admin_email = trim( get_option( 'admin_email' ) );
$admin_user = get_user_by( 'email', $admin_email ) );
$phone_number = get_user_meta($admin_user->ID, 'phone', true);
if($phone_number!='') { ?>
<?php echo $phone_number; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?></p>
```

I've also replaced your `get_blog_option()` with the simpler [`get_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option), since `get_blog_option()` essentially does `switch_to_blog()`, `get_option()`, and `restore_current_blog()`. Since you're going after the information in the *current* blog anyway, the `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` are superfluous.

If this code doesn't work, do some debugging -- add in `var_dump( $admin_email)` to verify that the `get_option()` retrieved something, etc.

**Edited to respond to comments**

When you create a new site in WordPress Multisite, you are asked for an administrative email address.  That user will be assigned as the site's first administrator.  However, if that user is then removed from the site, the `admin_email` option is not removed from the database.

Check your user list in your `wp-admin` pages, and make sure that there is, in fact, an administrator-level user with *exactly* the same email address that you got from your `var_dump( $admin_email );` call.  If there is, count the number of characters in the email address.  I'm wondering if you're seeing a whitespace issue (eg, an extra space inserted in the `$admin_email` or something).  I've added `trim()` to the code sample, but I may be grasping at straws.

Comment: Ok i tried it, and it didnt echo nothing out, but when i added var dump. it did echo out the admin email.

Comment: All right. What about `var_dump( $admin_user );` & `var_dump( $phone_number );` after their respective definitions?

Comment: I got this result - bool(false) bool(false)

Comment: with this code `<?php
$admin_email = get_option( 'admin_email' );
$admin_user = get_user_by( 'email', $admin_email );
$phone_number = get_user_meta($admin_user->ID, 'phone', true);
var_dump( $admin_email);
var_dump( $admin_user );
var_dump( $phone_number );
if($phone_number!='') { ?>
<?php echo $phone_number; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: Updated my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: Like I've said many a time -- the hardest thing to debug are the little mistakes.  I take it you got it working, then?

Comment: Yeah, so far so good